# Input in C, special case?

Tags: c, string, dynamic, input

Good day,

I've got the following code:

```
 43     while (TRUE)
 44     {
 45         printf("Swipe Card: ");
 46         scanf("%s;%s=%s", id, banner, cp);
 47         printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", id, banner, cp);
 48         ProcessStudent(banner, file);
 49
 50     }
```

I've dynamically allocated `id`, `banner`, and `cp`, however when I try to print them (which I did just to check their contents) everything is taken into 'id' only. The string I'm trying to read looks like this `%GRE068?;01540594=000331!`

Comment: `;` and `=` are not whitespace.

Comment: True, my bad. I fixed it. Used `scanf("%[^;]%[^=]%[^\n]", id, banner, cp);
` instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf` doesn't try to do a full pattern match of the format string. `%s` input format simply reads everything up to the next whitespace (or EOF). After that, it looks for a `;`, and since it doesn't find that it doesn't parse any of the other inputs.

If you want to stop at some other character, use `[^char]`

```
scanf("[^;];%[^=]=%s", id, banner, cp);
```